# Polygons only display when data is called within leaflet()

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I am trying to map multiple layers of Polygons to a leaflet map. The polygons show up when added separately, but not together, throwing an error: "Error in derivePolygons(data, lng, lat, missing(lng), missing(lat), "addPolylines") : 
  addPolylines must be called with both lng and lat, or with neither"

I have three buffer files of class sfc_POLYGON that were created with the following code:

```
CCL2 <- read_sf([my file here])
class(CCL2)
#[1] "sf"         "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

CCL3<-st_combine(CCL2) 

#create a buffer of x miles about the CCL
buffer_1 <- st_buffer(CCL3, dist = .04)

buffer_2 <- st_buffer(CCL3, dist = .03)

buffer_3 <- st_buffer(CCL3, dist = .02)
```

What I would like to to do is have a leaflet that shows them all at once, with code along these lines:

```
bmap <- leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLines) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerBackground) %>%
  addPolylines(buffer_1, opacity = 1, col = "red") %>%
  addPolylines(buffer_2, opacity = 1, col = "blue") %>%
  addPolylines(buffer_3, opacity = 1, col = "green")

(AddTiles %>% does not seem to make a difference so I have left that out)
```

That code throws the error I mentioned above. 
I have tried so far:

- converting the sfc_POLYGON buffer file using Polygons().
- using addPolygons() instead of addPolylines()
- putting lng = NULL and lat = NULL as arguments

Basically, because the buffer have MULTILINESTRING / geometry data, they map individually [and look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b4Zt.png) This is the code that works:

```
bmap <- leaflet(buffer_1) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLines) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerBackground) %>%
  addPolylines(opacity = 1, col = "red")
```

Looking for help to see if there is any way to display all 3 buffers at once.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with polygons as well as polylines and it worked when I provided the argument `data = buffer_1` instead of just giving `buffer_1` as an argument.